# What are the New Initial D the Movies - Legends?

Tags: initial-d

I have watched all of the following:

- Initial D (referred to retroactively by fans as "First Stage") — 26 episodes (1998)
- Initial D Second Stage — 13 episodes (1999)
- Initial D Extra Stage — 2-episode OVA side-story focusing on Impact Blue (2000)
- Initial D Third Stage — a 114-minute movie (2001)
- Initial D Fourth Stage — 24 episodes (2004–2006)
- Initial D Extra Stage 2 — a 50-minute OVA side-story focusing on Mako and
- Iketani (2008)
- Initial D Fifth Stage — 14 episodes (2012–2013)
- Initial D: Final Stage — 4 episodes (TV), compilation movie (DVD/Blu-ray) (2014)

And the next things on this list are:

- New Initial D the Movie - Legend 1: Awakening — feature movie (2014)
- New Initial D the Movie - Legend 2: Racer — feature movie (2015)
- New Initial D the Movie - Legend 3: Dream — feature movie (2016)

Now I am wondering if they are worth watching, but not if they are good or bad, but what are they actually. Is this the whole story from all previous stages redone with new animations? Or does it have anything new in the story?

Comment: At the very least, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Initial_D_the_Movie) states that "*the movie is a retelling of the early stages of the manga*".

Comment: @AkiTanaka Yes, but that doesn't answer my question, whether this retelling is only new, nicer animation of older anime, or some new things from manga, which were left out of the original anime.